# jQuery smooth toggle css width between value and auto

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am looking to *smoothly* toggle the css width of a div between a value and auto. I currently have this, as this is the second-best option I know to achieve almost what I want.

**By doing this I am hoping to create a click menu which is as wide as the image and the name.**

```
$('#LoginButton').click(function(){
    $(this).css('width', 'auto'),
    $("#profile").delay(100).toggle(300);
});
```

Other toggle functions I found wouldn't work with "auto" as a value, which I find strange.

Next to the toggle option I would like the div and it's contents to "smoothly" widen, rather than pop up once it is clicked.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EverybdyLies/jaxpd/1/

Thank you.

Comment: if you're using css3, go all the way, and use transitions.  if not, reformat your code so you can work in `stop(true,false).animate({width:'toggle'})`.  i prefer css3 since all you have to do, jQuery-wise is `addClass('expandLogin')` and `removeClass('expandLogin')`.  with transitions, you only specify the css start & end points and the way it "transitions" (time, easing, etc).  `auto` is difficult with both unless if you use better `display` properties like `inline-block`

Comment: Right, that's exactly what I thought, @JoeCoderGuy! But I can't get it to change from 20px wide to auto - to reveal more content and adjust to it's width rather than a fixed width - but the animation is just really weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crux of the problem is that no one talks about `$.stop(true,false).animate({width: 'toggle'});` anymore (deprecated?).

Also, `display:inline-block` is very useful when you don't want to take all available space but don't want your element to be quite such a pushover as `display:inline`.

I changed it a little to show how it can be done, but there's still work that needs to be done to make the text display properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/CTms3/2/

jQuery (and any other js lib that animates) is still superior because css3 transitions (animations) still don't account for `auto` or collapse the space used by the element when shrinking with `transform: scale` (maybe there's a way, but i don't know what it is).

I also recommend you directly manipulate most animations with the first code above.  If you click the button rapidly in the fiddle, you'll notice that `#username` changes directions on each click while `#profile` doesn't yet keeps going back and forth.  That's because of `stop(true,false)`.  It interrupts the animation while the css is actually set to the final state.  Very convenient.

You're on a great track.  If you want to add more detail to the question or want to figure out how to make the text in `#username` display properly, please ask in a new one since this one is mostly likely answered at its' core.

Comment: I believe I solved this by floating the username left. Update: http://jsfiddle.net/EverybdyLies/CTms3/3/
So thanks a lot for your help, if I need further help I'll ask a new question.


Thank you, @JoeCoderGuy

Answer (score 0):

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaxpd/3/)

Its not optimized, but its clear enough (I hope) so you can see another way to do it smoothly.

```
$('#parent').mouseenter(function(){
        $("#LoginButton").css('width', '500'),
        $("#profile").delay(100).toggle(300);
});
$('#parent').mouseleave(function(){
        $("#LoginButton").css('width', '20'),
        $("#profile").delay(100).toggle(300);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. 
The point, however, is to create a _click_ menu which is as wide as the image and the name.(This is why I opted for an automatic width)
Thanks for this option though!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the animateAuto plugin http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/jaxpd/7/ :

```
jQuery.fn.animateAuto = function(prop, speed, callback){
    var elem, height, width;
    return this.each(function(i, el){
        el = jQuery(el), elem = el.clone().css({"height":"auto","width":"auto"}).appendTo("body");
        height = elem.css("height"),
        width = elem.css("width"),
        elem.remove();

        if(prop === "height")
            el.animate({"height":height}, speed, callback);
        else if(prop === "width")
            el.animate({"width":width}, speed, callback);  
        else if(prop === "both")
            el.animate({"width":width,"height":height}, speed, callback);
    });  
}



$('#LoginButton').toggle(

function () {
    $(this).stop().animateAuto('width',600);
    $("#profile").delay(100).toggle(300);
},

function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: '20px'
    })
    $("#profile").delay(100).toggle(300);
});
```

**Update** To use jquery 1.9 and above the toggle function behaviour has changed a bit : http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed So to use it with those you need the migrate plugin. Sample with jQuery 1.9 and migrate 1.1 : http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/jaxpd/18/

Comment: Great, thanks. It works great in the fiddle, however when integrated in my page using this Facebook plugin: http://dft.ba/-5zuM it stays hidden with _display:none_ somehow. (Can I ask follow-up questions through comments?)
Thanks for the working script, too bad I can't make it work with Facebook.

Comment: You comment is not really a follow up question so the comment is fine. It is really an elaboration. For answer look at the update.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of a hack, but try something like this.

```
$('#LoginButton').click(function()
{
    // Show the menu, but offscreen
    var profile = $('#profile')
        .css('position', 'absolute')
        .css('left', '-10000px')
        .css('top', '0')
        .show ();

    // Get the width of the menu
    var width = profile.width ();

    // Hide the menu and put it back into document flow
    profile
        .hide()
        .css('position', 'static')
        .delay(100)
        .toggle(300);

    // Resize the login button
$(this).animate({'width': width}, 500);
});
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jaxpd/17/)